# how to write if statement to see if the table exists in the dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery , how do I get the scalar variable to see if the table already exist in the dataset?

````
IF (SELECT * FROM DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name='XXXX') is not null 
then 
TRUNCATE TABLE `DATASET.TABLE`;

END IF;

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`EXISTS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if) eg

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name='XXXX')
THEN
    TRUNCATE TABLE `DATASET.XXXX`;
END IF;
```

Let me know if this works for you